# Isolating Digits of Large Number (iOS-Xcode)

Tags: iphone, ios

I am having an issue with separating the digits in a 9-digit number. I am doing this using the following method:

Note: It might be easier to paste thuis into Xcode to 'see' it more easily:

```
int firstDigit = currentValue *.00000001; // = 3.7 = 3
firstDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",firstDigit];
int secondDigit = (currentValue *.0000001) - (firstDigit *10); // = 7.2 = 7
secondDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondDigit];
int thirdDigit = (currentValue *.000001) - ((firstDigit *100)+(secondDigit*10)); // = 2.8 = 2
thirdDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",thirdDigit];
int fourthDigit = (currentValue *.00001) - ((firstDigit *1000)+(secondDigit*100)+(thirdDigit*10)); // = 2.8 = 2
fourthDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fourthDigit];
int fifthDigit = (currentValue *.0001) - ((firstDigit *10000)+(secondDigit*1000)+(thirdDigit*100)+(fourthDigit*10));
fifthDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fifthDigit];
int sixthDigit = (currentValue *.001) - ((firstDigit *100000)+(secondDigit*10000)+(thirdDigit*1000)+(fourthDigit*100)+(fifthDigit*10));
sixthDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sixthDigit];
int seventhDigit = (currentValue *.01) - ((firstDigit *1000000)+(secondDigit*100000)+(thirdDigit*10000)+(fourthDigit*1000)+(fifthDigit*100)+(sixthDigit*10));
seventhDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seventhDigit];
int eighthDigit = (currentValue *.1) - ((firstDigit *10000000)+(secondDigit*1000000)+(thirdDigit*100000)+(fourthDigit*10000)+(fifthDigit*1000)+(sixthDigit*100)+(seventhDigit*10));
eighthDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",eighthDigit];

int ninthDigit = (currentValue *1) - ((firstDigit *100000000)+(secondDigit*10000000)+(thirdDigit*1000000)+(fourthDigit*100000)+(fifthDigit*10000)+(sixthDigit*1000)+(seventhDigit*100)+(eighthDigit*10)+1);
ninthDigitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ninthDigit];
```

Although this works to find the first 7 digits, I am having problems with finding the 8th, and consequently 9th digit (they build off each other). It's wierd because when I do the math myself using the 8th and 9th digit equations, they work, and it's only when I add them to the app that they start messing up.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a more efficient (and readable) way to do it:

```
int currentValue = someNineDigitNumber;
NSString *currentValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i",currentValue];

NSString *firstDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
NSString *secondDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(1,1)];
NSString *thirdDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(2,1)];
NSString *fourthDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(3,1)];
NSString *fifthDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(4,1)];
NSString *sixthDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(5,1)];
NSString *seventhDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(6,1)];
NSString *eighthDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(7,1)];
NSString *ninthDigit = [currentValueString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(8,1)];

firstDigitLabel.text = firstDigit;
secondDigitLabel.text = secondDigit;
thirdDigitLabel.text = thirdDigit;
fourthDigitLabel.text = fourthDigit;
fifthDigitLabel.text = fifthDigit;
sixthDigitLabel.text = sixthDigit;
seventhDigitLabel.text = seventhDigit;
eighthDigitLabel.text = eighthDigit;
ninthDigitLabel.text = ninthDigit;
```

If you have any questions about the code, just ask in the comments. Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but I will try it out. Thanks for the help, I'll be back later to let you know if it works.

Comment: Sure. Take your time. Just a note: in all the `NSMakeRange` functions, you **might** have to shift the first parameter one value forward. For example, `NSMakeRange(0,1)` becomes `NSMakeRange(1,1)`, `NSMakeRange(1,1)` becomes `NSMakeRange(2,1)`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be unaware of the division (`/`) and modulo (`%`) operators.  You can use the modulo operator (`%`) to get the units digit of the value, and then use the division operator (`/`) to remove that digit and shift all of the other digits down.

```
int digits[9];
int value = currentValue;
BOOL isNegative = value < 0;
if (isNegative) {
    value = -value;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    digits[8 - i] = value % 10;
    value /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Nailed it!  This would have been my answer, so +1 for you :)